# Multiple Vue.js components with same Vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuex

In component 1, there is some data being loaded using async method and stored in Vuex store. Same store is being used by other component 2 and data must be  cleared when the user navigates from component 1 to component 2.

Below is the normal workflow which is working fine.

1. Component 1 - load data completed (async, await)
2. User navigates to Component 2
3. Component 1 data is cleared in deactivated event
4. Component 2 is displayed fine

Now, when the user opens the component 1 and quickly navigates to the component 2.

1. Component 1 - **data request initiated but data is not loaded yet**
2. User navigates to Component 2
3. Component 1 data is cleared in deactivated event
4. Component 1 async operation completed and data is loaded into the state now
5. Component 2 will display data meant for Component 1

Comment: Why are you storing a local state in a global vuex store? To me it sounds like that you are abusing the store for something it isn't meant to do.

Comment: You can add a state to check user current navigated page and  set a flag in store mutation to update state only user is in correct component else just ignore

Comment: @Sumurai8 There are other common components being used like the navigation tree in Component 1 and Component 2 are same just the data is different.

Comment: @chans, Thank you, it is a good solution

Comment: @Sunny do upvote the below solution, Thanks in advance

Comment: One way: wire the navigation logic (after) the **commit** of component 1 data cleanup that resolves with dispatched **`action`** and then change the route. This comes with the `async` api latency tradeoff ofcouse if thats not too mcuh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still think that you should restructure your components so it loads the data in a view component instead of in the store. The store is meant for data that is shared between different views, or at least relevant to a wider portion of the application, while your data seems specific to one view only. Just pass down the data via props instead.

```
Views
- View A
- View B
Components
  Common
    - Sidebar (the common sidebar that is loaded in both View A and View B)
  - Some other components specific to view a and b
```

If you intend to continue with using the store for local data, I think you have multiple options:

- You could key your loader with the url or the view name. Where in your state you normally just would have the data, you now have an object that maps the route or the view name to some data. You then use a getter that automatically gets the correct data for you. The added benefit for this is that you can leave your data in if you prefer, which speeds up loading when you return to that view (you don't have to do an api call anymore).
- You commit some token to the store and only override the data in your store state when the token matches the retrieve token. (e.g. `dispatch('get/my/data', { token: 'asdf' })` while previously doing `commit('switch/to/view', 'asdf')`. If the view does not match the view we are currently on, we simply discard the data.

In both cases you would dispatch your loading action with something like `dispatch('get/my/data', { view: this.$options.name })` (or: `this.$route.path` or `this.$route.name`)

If you go with the route of using the component name, you will have to do a commit as well as outlined above. Otherwise you can simply import your router with `import router from '../router'` or something similar.

For the first option you get something like this:

import router from '../router';
import Vue from 'vue';

```
{
  state: {
    data: {},
  },
  getters: {
    getData (state) {
      return state.data[router.currentRoute.path];
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setData (state, { view, data }) {
      Vue.$set(state.data, view, data);
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async fetchData ({ commit }, { view }) {
      const data = await myApiPromise;

      commit('setData', { view, data });
    }
  }
}
```

Now `getData` either returns data if you have loaded data for that view, or `undefined` if you haven't. Switching will simply grab the previously stored data, which may or may be useful to you.

The second option is similar, but you have an extra mutation to worry about. That mutation is called from `created` in each view. Don't worry about cleaning up after yourself when destroying the component, but rather cleanup just before doing the fetch.

```
{
  state: {
    data: null,
    view: '',
  },
  getters: {
    getData (state) {
      return state.data[router.currentRoute.path];
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    clearData (state) {
      Vue.$set(state, 'data', null);
    },
    setData (state, { view, data }) {
      if (state.view !== view) {
        // Do not update
        return;
      }

      Vue.$set(state, 'data', data);
    },

    setView (state, { view }) {
      Vue.$set(state, 'view', view);
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async fetchData ({ commit }, { view }) {
      commit('clearData');
      const data = await myApiPromise;

      commit('setData', { view, data });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use destroyed callback in Vue lifecycle to clear the store when user Navigates from component 1 to component 2

Aource: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#destroyed

You can still add a state to check user current navigated page and set a flag in store mutation to update state only user is in expected component else just ignore

Comment: This is what OP is already doing, but the beauty of concurrency is that your promise (probably an api call) can complete after the component has been destroyed, causing it to load the wrong data.